# How to run embedded vert.x?

Tags: java, program-entry-point, vert.x

I've wrote a Groovy MainApp with main(args).

When I launch it, the JVM exit directly (*"End of JVM execution !"*).

```
import org.vertx.groovy.core.Vertx

class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vertx vertx = VertxFactory.newVertx();

        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler{ request -> 
            println "A request has arrived on the server!" 
        }.listen(8080)

        println "End of JVM execution !"
    }
}
```

How to run correctly an **embedded** HTTP server with vert.x?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Java. I ended up putting an object in .wait() after all the vert.x code.
Looks horrible, but actually makes sense because it gives me a trigger to shutdown the server on demand (via .notify()).

This is non trivial, should be mentioned on the Vert.x official documentation.

Comment: Faced it too, it seems vertx have no time to start in non-cluster mode and jvm stops before. I solved it with `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` in the end: https://gist.github.com/yetanothercoder/21a2b47b686d902c5fee

Comment: @yetanothercoder any reason why not to use `.wait`/`.notify`?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this. I tried passing the hostname then it worked fine.

Vertx vertx = Vertx.newVertx(**"hostname"**)

I guess there is some issue determining the IP address while running locally and it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

```
RouteMatcher routeMatcher = new RouteMatcher();

        // HTTP server
        HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
        httpServer.requestHandler(routeMatcher);
httpServer.listen(7777);
```

Answer (score 0):

taken from documentation: http://vertx.io/embedding_manual.html:

just wait for input from System.in:

```
// Prevent the JVM from exiting
System.in.read();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentations:

```
all Vert.x threads are daemon threads and they will not prevent the JVM for exiting. Therefore you must ensure that the main() method does not run to completion, e.g. in this example we have used System.in.read() to block the main thread waiting for IO from the console.
```

So, you need to add the following at the end of your main method like this:

```
// Prevent the JVM from exiting
System.in.read();
```